# Test JSF application on multiple servers with same JMeter test script

Tags: jsf, testing, jmeter

At the moment we are developing an application and deploying it in my local machine. And now I'm doing a load test using jmeter and it runs without a issue. The problem I'm getting is when I try to run the same test on a different machine with a different server it doesn't work. 
And I observed that *html element id's* are different on different servers with JSF.(Issue is form submissions are not working). Is there a way to overcome this issue with jmeter since I want to run the same test scripts on different servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process of extracting dynamic values from previous response and adding them to next request is called correlation. JMeter provides variety of [Pre Processors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#preprocessors) and [Post Processors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) to allow modification of requests on-the-fly.

Example use case:

1. Send a GET request a JSP page which contains a number of inputs
2. Extract all the inputs names and populate values where required
3. Populate dynamic fields of next request with values extracted in point 2
4. Send a POST request

**Point 1**: No changes to your script required

**Point 2**:

Add [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) as a child of GET Request and populate it as follows:

- Reference Name: `INPUT`
- XPath Query: `//input/@name | //input[@type='hidden']`

This extractor will fetch all `<input>` HTML elements and store it to JMeter Variables as

```
INPUT_1=javax.faces.ViewState
INPUT_2=loginForm_SUBMIT
INPUT3=...
...
```

Add a Beanshell Pre Processor as a child of next request with the following code

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;


Iterator iter = vars.getIterator();
while (iter.hasNext())
{
    Map.Entry e = (Map.Entry)iter.next();
    if (e.getValue() != null)
    {
        if (e.getKey().toString().startsWith("INPUT_") && e.getValue().toString().length() >0)
        {
           sampler.addArgument(e.getValue().toString(),"VALUE OF YOUR INPUT");
        }
    }
}
```

The code above will fetch all variables prefixed with `INPUT_` and add it as parameters to your next request.

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on Beanshell scripting in Apache JMeter to see what else can be done using Beanshell scripting and using of JMeter objects exposed to Beanshell test elements.

Comment: This is exactly I would want. I also thought of using regex like I'm using to get the jsf viewstate. But didn't know about beanshell. Kind of new to jmeter. Will accept this answer.